# Why use a gaussian low pass filter, when we can convolve with gaussian kernel

Tags: image-processing, fft, convolution, lowpass-filter

Sorry if this question is too simplistic, but I am new to image processing and after successfully writing two programs, a convolution program and a low pass filtering program, I noticed that for approximately the same output, the low pass filtering method takes 4 times the time!

Lets assume that the image is a square of side `N`. When convolving we can use an arbitrarily small kernel (out to $3\sigma$ for example) and put a Gaussian in it, say of size `M`=$3\sigma$. We then have to simply pad the image and the kernel into an `N+M-1` side square array and run DFT onit, multiply it and run IDFT.

But for low pass filtering we have to create a padded square array of width `2*N`. There is one less DFT required, but the one DFT and the IDFT on the array with 4 times the elements will take a significantly longer amount of time because the padded array is huge (look at Gonzalez&Woods Fig.4.36 as an example)! Since the DFT of a Gaussian kernel is also a Gaussian, then why should we use a Gaussian low pass filtering at all when it takes nearly 4 times the time (look below)?

**Source code:** I have put the source code [in github](https://github.com/makhlaghi/freqdomain).

I am adding some timings in my program to show what I mean. The image was 233*233 pixels. My `CPU` is clocked at 3.07GHz.

For a low pass filter, note that the FFTs and IFFTs are done on an array of size 466*466:

```
Gaussian low pass filter timing:

Padding:                0.002564 (seconds)
FFT:                    0.018210 (seconds)
Applying filter:        0.006686 (seconds)
IFFT:                   0.017254 (seconds)
Time for final step:    0.000550 (seconds)

Total:                  0.047424 (seconds)
```

For a convolution of the same image with a kernel of size 9*9, note that the three FFTs and IFFTs are done on arrays of size 241*241:

```
Gaussian convolution timing:

Making the kernel:      0.000077 (seconds)
Pad both to same size:  0.001389 (seconds)
Padded image FFT:       0.002699 (seconds)
Padded kernel FFT:      0.001866 (seconds)
Multiplying:            0.000384 (seconds)
IFFT:                   0.002241 (seconds)
Crop from padded:       0.000574 (seconds)

Total:          0.011149 (seconds)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `FFT` instead of raw `DFT`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `FFTW` in `C`.

Comment: If for both methods you use same code structures then comparing complexity of two methods would be the key answer to your question.

Comment: I added some information about the timings. The logic is very simple: For a LPF you need FFT to work on N*N pixels. While for convolution you just need to work on two N+M-1 arrays. It is clear that LPF will be much more time consuming as long is M is small.

Comment: @makhlahgi In the kernel method how many convolution is done?

Comment: Only one! I run FFT on the kernel and image (both padded to a square of N+M-1), then I multiply their frequency domain arrays and run IFFT on the result. All of this is one convolution, am I correct?

Comment: Correction to a previous comment: ...For a LPF you need FFT to work on 2N*2N pixels. While for convolution you just need to work on two (N+M-1)*(N+M-1) arrays...

Comment: You don't need to do the FFT on the kernel, just use its frequency domain expression to directly multiple the FFT of the image. Also see what happens when you increase the size of the kernel.

Comment: @geometrikal, the multiplication in the frequency domain is what I have called a low pass filter(LPF). The problem is that the size of the array that has to undergo FFT and IFFT in an LPF is 2N*2N which is much slower than two (N+M-1)*(N+M-1) arrays, unless M is close to N.

Comment: @makhlaghi Thanks, I was reading your question wrongly. I don't think you really need to pad the image to 2N. For example, if 3 sigma of the kernel is contained within a 2M+1 x 2M+1 region, just pad by M pixels. Yes, there is a slight error, but in the second version cutting the kernel off at MxM before the FFT also introduces an error.

Comment: Also, convolution is the spatial domain filtering operation. Multiplication is the Fourier domain filtering operation, and is what you are actually doing in both. Unfortunately, you can't use the justification that your kernel was cropped to 2M+1 wide in the spatial domain to only pad by M before doing an FFT.

Comment: You can just pad by M if you were doing actual spatial domain convolution though.

Comment: @geometrikal, thanks. By a (2M+1)x(2M+1) array, do you mean the convolution kernel? In that case this is exactly what I am doing. For LPF I cannot use the same padding, I need atleast a 2Nx2N array.

Comment: I added the source code I am using to get these results in Github. You can see it in the question.

Comment: @makhlaghi Check out this link (and the intro) for convolution (in the spatial domain). ftp://ftp.isy.liu.se/pub/colour/misc/convolution.txt Conceptually, convolution is filtering. In your case both ways could be called 'low pass filtering'. In both, you are filtering via multiplication the Fourier domain so its not technically convolution. Convolution is kind of a shift-multiply-add of the spatial kernel and the image. Using your LPF method (the second one) if your kernel is well approximated when restricted to M x M pixels, then padding the image to N+M-1, not 2N, will be fine.

Comment: I understood. Thank you. I am familiar with the shift-multiply-add method. Infact that was my first method to implement convolution, but it was too slow. I will try the code you proposed and see if it is more efficient or not. Thanks again.

Comment: No problems, I bet the OpenCV implementation would be good too.

Comment: It seems openCV is mainly for C++, but generally I like to write my functions my self so I intuitively understand their shortcommings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice gaussian low-pass filters are written using F.I.R. or I.I.R. filters, first the filter runs left then right on each horizontal line, then the filter runs up then down on each vertical line.  It's much cheaper than doing FFTs and IFFTs.

Your two operations are not performing the same operation.  The effects of the filtering around the edges will be very different.  You are doing a *circular* convolution.  For the Discrete Fourier Transform the convolution theorem says that the multiplication of fourier transforms is equivalent to convolving the image infinitely repeated/tiled in the plane.  So around the left edge, for example you are blurring together some components from the right side of the picture.  (For example try performing your operations on a picture that is black on the left half and white on the right half.)

Your "low pass" filter is padding the image and the kernel to try to reduce some of the edge effects.  It's more expensive, but it is closer to what you would get if you did a "real" convolution of a gaussian with your image.

In your application the circular convolution effect of blurring in data from the other side of the image may be okay, but in many application it is unacceptable.

As to the reason that the FFT of an $N\times N$ image is 10 times faster than the FFT of a $2N \times 2N$ image.  A 2d FFT is done by taking 1d FFTs of each horizontal line, then 1d FFTs of each vertical line.  So in the $N \times N$ case you are doing $2N$ 1-d FFTs, each of which take $O(N \log N)$ for a total of $O(2N^2 \log N)$.  In the $2 N \times 2 N$ case you are doing $4N$ 1-d FFTs each of which take $O(2N \log 2N)$ for a total of (a little more than) $O(8N^2 \log N)$.  Add in cache effects for the larger image and 10x slower seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. I was not familiar with IIR filters! Do you know of its implementation in `C`? Or anywhere explaining the details of its algorithm so I can write it my self?

Comment: The code for an [I.I.R. filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) is trivial.  The hard parts are (a) choosing the coefficients and (b) dealing with the transients at the edges.  In general Matlab is used to help design the filter.  In the case of gaussians the filters are based on the following paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.12.2826.  A nice tutorial is http://www.cwp.mines.edu/Meetings/Project06/cwp546.pdf‎.  Ways of dealing with transients are described in http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00548616/en.

Comment: I understand the edge problem you explained and saw it in my programs. I am reading about IIR filters now. Based on your explanations (..."but in many application it is unacceptable."), I understand that the edge-effect is removed with these implementations, am I correct?

Comment: That last paper (the one from hal.inria.fr) is specifically about dealing with the edge effects.  It's actually a bit tricky to do it efficiently.

Comment: So I am curious how people convolve or apply LPF when such edge effects are unacceptable and applying that technique is tricky?

Comment: "In practice gaussian low-pass filters are written using I.I.R. filters". I have never heard of this before, can you provide a link about this? I thought gaussian filters are always FIRs.

Comment: I read the papers, they are approximating the Gaussian with another function! I don't understand why they do that (I am not a software engineer or computer scientist, sorry if this seems silly!)!?! Can't they just sample from the actual Gaussian?

Comment: The Gaussian kernel has some special scale-space properties. A discrete kernel made from sampling the continuous Gaussian does not, and instead they use a slightly modified kernel - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation#The_discrete_Gaussian_kernel

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: I seem to have overstated, so will modify that first sentence.  GIMP and GEGL use IIR filters for wide Gaussians.  But ImageMagick seems to use multiple FIR passes for wide Gaussians while netpbm and OpenCV just create a wide FIR filter.  The http://www.cwp.mines.edu/Meetings/Project06/cwp546.pdf paper suggests that FIR is faster for $\sigma < 3$, which is probably the common case.